# How to convert .shp file into .csv in R?

Tags: r, maps, shapes, spatial

I want to to convert two .shp files into one database that would allow me to draw the maps together.

Also, is there a way to convert .shp files into .csv files? I want to be able to personalize and add some data which is easier for me under a .csv format. What I have in mind if to add overlay yield data and precipitation data on the maps.

Here are the shapefiles for [Morocco](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0jnmj4byrmzn0r/MAR_adm1.shp), and [Western Sahara](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qqo0ykid3bstpb/ESH_adm1.shp).

Code to plot the two files:

```
# This is code for mapping of CGE_Morocco results

# Loading administrative coordinates for Morocco maps
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)

# Loading shape files
Mor <- readShapeSpatial("F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/Country-CGE/MAR_adm1.shp")
Sah <- readShapeSpatial("F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/Country-CGE/ESH_adm1.shp")

# Ploting the maps (raw)
png("Morocco.png")
Morocco <- readShapePoly("F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/Country-CGE/MAR_adm1.shp")
plot(Morocco)
dev.off()

png("WesternSahara.png")
WesternSahara <- readShapePoly("F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/Country-CGE/ESH_adm1.shp")
plot(WesternSahara)
dev.off()
```

[image: Morocco]
[image: WesternSahara]

After looking into suggestions from @AriBFriedman and @PaulHiemstra and subsequently figuring out how to merge .shp files, I have managed to produce the following map using the following code and data (For .shp data, cf. links above)

code:

```
# Merging Mor and Sah .shp files into one .shp file

MoroccoData <- rbind(Mor@data,Sah@data) # First, 'stack' the attribute list rows using rbind() 
MoroccoPolys <- c(Mor@polygons,Sah@polygons) # Next, combine the two polygon lists into a single list using c()

summary(MoroccoData)
summary(MoroccoPolys)

offset <- length(MoroccoPolys) # Next, generate a new polygon ID for the new SpatialPolygonDataFrame object

browser()
for (i in 1: offset)
{
sNew =  as.character(i)
MoroccoPolys[[i]]@ID = sNew
}

ID <- c(as.character(1:length(MoroccoPolys))) # Create an identical ID field and append it to the merged Data component
MoroccoDataWithID <- cbind(ID,MoroccoData)

MoroccoPolysSP <- SpatialPolygons(MoroccoPolys,proj4string=CRS(proj4string(Sah))) #  Promote the merged list to a SpatialPolygons data object

Morocco <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(MoroccoPolysSP,data = MoroccoDataWithID,match.ID = FALSE) #  Combine the merged Data and Polygon components into a new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Morocco@data$id <- rownames(Morocco@data)
Morocco.fort <- fortify(Morocco, region='id') 
Morocco.fort <- Morocco.fort[order(Morocco.fort$order), ] 

MoroccoMap <- ggplot(data=Morocco.fort, aes(long, lat, group=group)) + 
geom_polygon(colour='black',fill='white') + 
theme_bw()
```

Results:

[image: MoroccoMAp]

New Question:

1- How to eliminate the boundaries data that cuts though the map in half?

2- How to combine different regions within a .shp file?

Thanks you all.

P.S: the community in stackoverflow.com is wonderful and very helpful, and especially toward beginners like :) Just thought of emphasizing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have loaded your shapefiles into Spatial{Lines/Polygons}DataFrames (classes from the sp-package), you can use the `fortify` generic function to transform them to flat data.frame format. The specific functions for the `fortify` generic are included in the `ggplot2` package, so you'll need to load that first. A code example:

```
library(ggplot2)
polygon_dataframe = fortify(polygon_spdf)
```

where `polygon_spdf` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. A similar approach works for `SpatialLinesDataFrame`'s.

The difference between my solution and that of @AriBFriedman is that mine includes the `x` and `y` coordinates of the polygons/lines, in addition to the data associated to those polgons/lines. I really like visualising my spatial data with the `ggplot2` package.

Once you have your data in a normal `data.frame` you can simply use `write.csv` to generate a csv file on disk.

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean you want the associated data.frame from each?

If so, it can be accessed with the `@` slot access function.  The slot is called `data`:

```
write.csv( WesternSahara@data, file="/home/wherever/myWesternSahara.csv")
```

Then when you read it back in with `read.csv`, you can try assigning:

```
myEdits <- read.csv("/home/wherever/myWesternSahara_modified.csv")
WesternSahara@data <- myEdits
```

You may need to do some massaging of row names and so forth to get it to accept the new data.frame as valid.  I'd probably try to merge the existing data.frame with a csv you read in in R, rather than making edits destructively....

Comment: +1, although this does not include the spatial coordinates of the polygons/lines. For this you can use `fortify` after loading the `ggplot2` package, see my answer for more details.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra +1 to you for a nice use of `fortify`.  There's always a bit of crystal-ball gazing with questions like this, but my read of the OP's intent was to just add and clean up some of the associated values.  For that, the less that gets exported the better--I'm still nervous about the non-reproducibility of exporting everything to Excel, editing, and then reading back in, with either solution....

Comment: I'd really recommend the OP learn how to do the editing in R.